# ASP.Netcore MVC - Razor Displaying expense totals for categories by Month/Year rows and total expenses per month using efcore

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

[I am trying to create a table like the one below, with orders grouped by month and the perspective catergories that the orders fall under are totaled accordingly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41WGM.png)

I have also been able to either sort according to month/ year and get grand total or sort by category and get the total amounted for that category - but cannot figure out how to combine them together.

this creates action allows for month group

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExpensesPaymentList()
    {

        var model = _context.Requests.Include(r => r.Product)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.ProductSubcategory)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.ParentCategory)
            .GroupBy(r => new
            {
                Month = r.ParentRequest.OrderDate.Month,
                Year = r.ParentRequest.OrderDate.Year,
            })

            .Select(g => new MonthlyTotalsViewModel
            {
                Month = g.Key.Month,
                Year = g.Key.Year,
                GrandTotal = g.Sum(r => r.Cost)
            })
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.Year)
            .ThenByDescending(a => a.Month)
            .ToList();

        return View(await model.ToListAsync());
    }
```

this creates action allows for category group

```
    public ActionResult ExpensesPaymentList()
    {
        var model = _context.Requests.Include(r => r.Product)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.ProductSubcategory)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.ParentCategory)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => new
            {
                ParentCategory = r.Product.ProductSubcategory.ParentCategory,
            })
            .Select(g => new ExpensesPaymentListViewModel
            {
                ParentCategory = g.Key.ParentCategory,
                Total = g.Sum(r => r.Cost)
            })
            .ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

My viewModels:

```
public class ExpensesPaymentListViewModel
{
    public ParentCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
}
public class MonthlyTotalsViewModel
{
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public double GrandTotal { get; set; }
}
```

I am open to any suggestions or to try something completely new - I have been stuck on this for days.
thank you!

**edit:** 
I have also tried using a where in the select and hard coding the various categories and binding them to the viewModelbut Linq says that it is not valid query. See below

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExpensesPaymentList()
    {

        var model = _context.Requests.Include(r => r.Product)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.ProductSubcategory)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.ParentCategory)
            .GroupBy(r => new
            {
                Month = r.ParentRequest.OrderDate.Month,
                Year = r.ParentRequest.OrderDate.Year,
            })

            .Select(g => new MonthlyTotalsViewModel
            {
                Month = g.Key.Month,
                Year = g.Key.Year,
                PlasticsTotal = g.Where(g => g.Product.ProductSubcategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategoryID == 1).Sum(r => r.Cost),
                ReagentsTotal = g.Where(g => g.Product.ProductSubcategory.ParentCategory.ParentCategoryID == 2).Sum(r => r.Cost), 
                  //and so on for the rest of my parentcategories
                GrandTotal = g.Sum(r => r.Cost)
            })
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.Year)
            .ThenByDescending(a => a.Month)
            .ToList();

        return View(await model.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the same form of logic, but it should solve the problem. The output is exactly what it needs to be

Model:

```
public class MonthlyTotalsModel
    {

        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public double GrandTotal { get; set; }
        public double PlasticsTotal { get; set; }
        public double ReagentsTotal { get; set; }
        public double ProprietyTotal { get; set; }
        public double ReusableTotal { get; set; }

    }
```

ViewModel

```
    public class ExpensesListViewModel
    {
        public List<MonthlyTotalsViewModel> monthlyTotals { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExpensesList()
    {
        List<MonthlyTotalsViewModel> monthlyTotals = new List<MonthlyTotalsViewModel>();

        var requestsByMonthAndYear = _context.Requests.Select(r => new { Year = r.ParentRequest.OrderDate.Year, Month = r.ParentRequest.OrderDate.Month }).Distinct();
        foreach (var req in requestsByMonthAndYear)
        {
            var requestsinMonthAndYear = _context.Requests.Include(r => r.ParentRequest).Include(r => r.Product).ThenInclude(p => p.ProductSubcategory).ThenInclude(p => p.ParentCategory).Where(r => r.ParentRequest.OrderDate.Year == req.Year).Where(r => r.ParentRequest.OrderDate.Month == req.Month).ToList();
            MonthlyTotalsViewModel monthlyTotalsViewModel = new MonthlyTotalsViewModel
            {
                Month = req.Month,
                Year = req.Year,
                GrandTotal = requestsinMonthAndYear.Sum(r => r.Cost),
                PlasticsTotal = requestsinMonthAndYear.Where(r => r.Product.ProductSubcategory.ParentCategoryID == 1).AsEnumerable().Sum(m => m.Cost),
                ReagentsTotal = requestsinMonthAndYear.Where(r => r.Product.ProductSubcategory.ParentCategoryID == 2).AsEnumerable().Sum(m => m.Cost),
                ProprietyTotal = requestsinMonthAndYear.Where(r => r.Product.ProductSubcategory.ParentCategoryID == 3).AsEnumerable().Sum(m => m.Cost),
                ReusableTotal = requestsinMonthAndYear.Where(r => r.Product.ProductSubcategory.ParentCategoryID == 4).AsEnumerable().Sum(m => m.Cost)
            }
            monthlyTotals.Add(monthlyTotalsViewModel);
        }

        ExpensesListViewModel expensesListViewModel = new ExpensesListViewModel
        {
            monthlyTotals = monthlyTotals
        };

        return View(expensesListViewModel);
    }
```

View

```
@model PrototypeWithAuth.ViewModels.ExpensesListViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ExpensesList";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/PaymentView.cshtml";
}

<h1>ExpensesList</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>
        Month - Year
    </th>
    <th>
        Plastics
    </th>
    <th>
        Reagents
    </th>
    <th>
        Proprietry
    </th>
    <th>
        Reusable
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach(var item in Model.monthlyTotals)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Month - @item.Year
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.PlasticsTotal
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.ReagentsTotal
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.ProprietyTotal
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.ReusableTotal
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```